# Problem with the vertical alignment in a table

Tags: tables

I am working on the table below.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c || c |} 
\hline
\# Edges & \# Configurations \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
0 & $c(0)=1$ \\     [0.5ex] 
\hline
4 & $c(4)=9$ \\     [0.5ex] 
\hline
6 & $c(6)=12$ \\    [0.5ex] 
\hline
8 & $c(8)= 50$ \\   [0.5ex] 
\hline
10 & $c(10)= 92$ \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline
12 & $c(12)=158$ \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline
14 & $c(14)=116$ \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline
16 & $c(16)=69$ \\  [0.5ex] 
\hline
18 & $c(18)=4$ \\   [0.5ex] 
\hline
20 & $c(20)=1$ \\   [0.5ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}    
\end{center}
```

The arguments in the second column are not aligned vertically (picture below).

[image: Rendering of the example's table]

Is there any easy to solve this?

Comment: Please make the code ready for copy & compile. // Suggestion: Please EDIT and post a screenshot, indicating your problem.

Comment: @MS-SPO, Please have a look now.

Comment: Do you need to repeat `c(n)`? The argument is already stated in the left column.

Comment: @ egreg. I do not think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an extra columns and set three last column as right-, centre-, and left-aligned.

Apart from that, I would avoid so many rules and limit the vertical bars to just one, at most. Here's my proposition

EDIT.
Slightly improved code to make horizontal padding around headers consistent.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newlength\collen
\newlength\eqlen
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\(}p{#1}<{\)}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\(}p{#1}<{\)}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbh]
    \sbox0{\# Edges}
    \sbox2{\# Configurations}
    \settowidth{\eqlen}{${}={}$}
    \setlength{\collen}{\dimexpr\wd2-\eqlen}

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{-1pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
            >{\(}c<{\)}   !{\vrule width 0.3pt}
            R{0.5\collen}
            @{\;}c@{\;}
            L{0.5\collen}
        }
        \noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
        \usebox0 & & \clap{\usebox2} & \\
        \noalign{\hrule height 0.5pt}
        0  & c(0)  &=& 1   \\
        4  & c(4)  &=& 9   \\
        6  & c(6)  &=& 12  \\
        8  & c(8)  &=& 50  \\
        10 & c(10) &=& 92  \\
        12 & c(12) &=& 158 \\
        14 & c(14) &=& 116 \\
        16 & c(16) &=& 69  \\
        18 & c(18) &=& 4   \\
        20 & c(20) &=& 1   \\
        \noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you'd use the `tabularray` package, setting the row height would be easy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={|c || c |},
  hlines,
  rows={ht=1.5\baselineskip}
}
\# Edges & \# Configurations \\ 
0 & $c(0)=1$ \\      
4 & $c(4)=9$ \\      
6 & $c(6)=12$ \\     
8 & $c(8)= 50$ \\    
10 & $c(10)= 92$ \\  
12 & $c(12)=158$ \\  
14 & $c(14)=116$ \\  
16 & $c(16)=69$ \\   
18 & $c(18)=4$ \\    
20 & $c(20)=1$ \\    
\end{tblr}    
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way you can reduce the vertical spacing cells a little smaller?

Comment: @Mass Change `ht=1.5\baselineskip` to whatever spacing you like

Answer (score 5):

I propose as samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz a solution with `tabularray`, and I use Celdor's choices for horizontal and vertical lines, and alignment of the `=`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
colspec={ Q[c,mode=math]  Q[wd=1.25cm,r,mode=math] @{\;} c  @{\;}  Q[wd=1.25cm,l,mode=math] },
%hlines,
rows={ht=1.1\baselineskip},
cell{1}{1}={r=1,c=1}{mode=text},%<--- to change the default math option
cell{1}{2}={r=1,c=3}{c,mode=text},%<--- for center \# Configurations of 3 colons
hline{1,Z} = {0.8pt,solid},
hline{2} = {0.5pt,solid},
vline{2} = {0.3pt,solid},
}
\# Edges & \# Configurations\\ 
0  & c(0)  &=& 1   \\
4  & c(4)  &=& 9   \\
6  & c(6)  &=& 12  \\
8  & c(8)  &=& 50  \\
10 & c(10) &=& 92  \\
12 & c(12) &=& 158 \\
14 & c(14) &=& 116 \\
16 & c(16) &=& 69  \\
18 & c(18) &=& 4   \\
20 & c(20) &=& 1   \\ 
\end{tblr}    
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, each cell in both the columns are aligned on top. Perhaps what you want is centre aligned cells. Try the following and for more details see the documentation of the tabularray package [Here](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|}
\hline
\# Edges & \# Configurations \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
0 & $c(0)=1$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
4 & $c(4)=9$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
6 & $c(6)=12$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
8 & $c(8)= 50$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
10 & $c(10)= 92$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
12 & $c(12)=158$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
14 & $c(14)=116$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
16 & $c(16)=69$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
18 & $c(18)=4$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
20 & $c(20)=1$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{|c||c|}
\hline
\# Edges & \# Configurations \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
0 & $c(0)=1$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
4 & $c(4)=9$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
6 & $c(6)=12$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
8 & $c(8)= 50$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
10 & $c(10)= 92$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
12 & $c(12)=158$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
14 & $c(14)=116$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
16 & $c(16)=69$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
18 & $c(18)=4$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
20 & $c(20)=1$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dr. Dinesh J. Karia@Thank you Sir.

Comment: Your MWE is copy of MWE from question ... it not use `tabularray` package as you claim in text.

Comment: @Mass  On Stackexchange, we do not thank. But if the answer solves your problem, we accept it. You can accept only one answer. Of course, you may upvote all answers that you like.

Comment: @Zarko First I have listed his code and then included the tblr environment.

Comment: Hm, why you repeat a question? This is (to my opinion) unnecessary and only distract readers like me, who not scroll your answer to see what you propose.

Answer (score 2):

A wee bit simplified version of @pascal974 answer (+1) but with all horizontal lines:

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
%\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, 
                 colspec= {|c | Q[r, wd=4em, mode=math] @{\;} Q[l, wd=4.4em, mode=math]|},
                 cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{c},
                 row{1} = {mode=text},
                 rowsep = 7pt
                }
\# Edges
    & \# Configurations \\
  0 &  c(0) & =  1 \\
  4 &  c(4) & =  9 \\
  6 &  c(6) & = 12 \\
  8 &  c(8) & = 50 \\
 10 & c(10) & = 92 \\
 12 & c(12) & =158 \\
 14 & c(14) & =116 \\
 16 & c(16) & = 69 \\
 18 & c(18) & =  4 \\
 20 & c(20) & =  1 \\
    \end{tblr}
%\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]